# Angular - how to bind angular variable to html and display

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a component and it has a ts file it contains html content as a variable.

para1= `<a href="www.google.com">sitename</a> more content`

I need to bind this paragraph in html like a html itself.

[sitename](https://google.com)

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular HTML binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548311/angular-html-binding)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use `innerHTML` in case your variable value contains HTML template.

Like this -

```
para1= "<a href="www.google.com">sitename</a> more content"
```

In html file -

```
<span [innerHTML]='para1'></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[ngx-dynamic-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dynamic-template)** to achieve this.

In your example where `para1= '<a href="www.google.com">sitename</a> . . .'`, you may have something like this:

```
<ng-template 
    dynamic-template
    [template]="para1"
>
</ng-template>
```

Don't forget your import:

```
import { NgxDynamicTemplateModule } from 'ngx-dynamic-template';

@NgModule({
    imports: [NgxDynamicTemplateModule.forRoot()]
})
```